# Angular 9 Accessibility: combine string and binding for arial-label

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria

In Angular 9, I have a button to edit a contact in a table of contacts.

```
   <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" aria-label="Edit Contact">
     <i class="icon-mini icon-pencil"></i>
   </button>
```

I obviously can add the `aria-label` to the icon button to say what it does, "edit contact".  But I'd like to say "Edit Contact Jim Jones", which in this table would be `{{contact.full_name}}`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> When binding to ARIA attributes in Angular, you must use the attr. prefix, as the ARIA specification depends specifically on HTML attributes rather than properties on DOM elements.

[source](https://angular.io/guide/accessibility)

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" [attr.aria-label]="contact?.full_name">
```

> Note that this syntax is only necessary for attribute bindings. Static ARIA attributes require no extra syntax.